# Why when I just click H key the if statement that required Ctrl + H?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a javascript code that overrides whatever is browser default (in this case opening a history tab) when pressing Ctrl + H. But the if statement also activates when you press just an H key where as other functions do require that Ctrl key

Here's my code:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {

    if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 83) {

        $('direct[button=style]').click();

        e.preventDefault();

    }

    if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 72) {

        $('direct[button=home]').click();

        e.preventDefault();

    }

    if (e.keyCode == 27) {

        $('direct[button=signout]').click();

        e.preventDefault();

    }

});
```

The H key has keyCode 72

And  `$('direct[button=style]').click();`  needs the Ctrl key to be pressed

Comment: What if the user clicks on the browser menu then click on history?

Comment: What line is triggered?

Comment: Pasted your code into JSFiddle and can't replicate the issue.

Comment: I believe this is browser specific problem can you try using this code in your first line?
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
 e = e || window.event;

Answer (score 0):

Please do as below and hope this helps.

1. First console.log(e.which), and see what is the value getting printed on click of control key.

   2. Then replace the e.ctrlKey with the logic:
      e.which == the value you got in the console.